# Add Data to a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have created a model with a List in it

```
namespace OMIv2._1KSWilson.Models
{
public class LegendClassVM
{
    public List <string> legendValues { get; set; }
}
}
```

then i have a foreach loop that creates strings that i want to use.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
        {
            if (f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode))
            {
                if (!values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()))
                {
                    values.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString());

                }
            }

        }
```

how would i add these items to the model list. this code executes five times so i need to store alot of data.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LegendClassVM model  = new LegendClassVM();
        model.legendValues = new List <string>();

    foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
    {
        if (f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode))
        {
            if (!values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()))
            {
              model.legendValues.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString());

            }
        }

    }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: wouldnt that replace all the data within the model list? since it creates a new model legend? @Daniel Gpe Reyes

Comment: what exactly you want to do? i mean, the loop that you have from where is called?, or you mean that you want to update the existing list with the new values? or  can you please be more clear in your question, thanks